# Persist data on postgres docker with a volume when restarting the container

Tags: docker

I have read stackoverflow posts, but could not find a solution to my problem of persisting data with a volume with postgres:

First i create a volume:

```
docker volume create pgdata
```

Then i run the postgres container:

```
docker run -d -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

Then i create a database connecting with sql:

```
psql postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres
```

After stopping the container i restart with:

```
docker run -d -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

The database is lost. Should it not stay there, because i use the same volume?

EDIT: PGDATA="/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" needs to be added and it works as well as the solution of David Maze

Comment: run 'docker volume inspect pgdata', is there a mount point specified?

Comment: yes, it is "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/pgdata/_data",

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Inside the [`postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), the PostgreSQL data directory is `/var/lib/postgresql/data`.  Unless you mount your volume on *exactly* this path, it won't get used.

```sh
docker run -d \
  -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \ # <-- add .../data
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  postgres
```

At a technical level, this is because the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/a1420dac644b8190df5e78e80bfa9610b2f077e2/12/Dockerfile#L181) declares `VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data`.  If nothing else is mounted on that exact path, this causes Docker to create an anonymous volume at `docker run` time and store the data there.  Since you're mounting a volume on the parent directory but not the exact path, this triggers the anonymous-volume case.

Comment: If i mount with: docker run -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 postgres
like you suggested, docker says, that the directory exists, but it is not empty, so it cannot start.

Comment: The existing volume probably has an empty directory named `data` in it, but nothing else.  Delete and recreate it.  (Or try `docker run --rm -it -v pgdata:/vol busybox sh` and look what's in `/vol` to see for real.)

Comment: Actually it has not, just a "pgdata" dir resides in volume. I solved the problem by adding PGDATA="/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"  as env, but do not understand, why it solved the problem nor why it does not work without it.